# Calculate price and quantity using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to calculate price and quantity. I don't want to remove currency type. The price is php generated so i just want to show a calculated price when update quantity using jquery or javascript. Thank you.

Here is working demo :

```js
$('input[name=\'quantity\']').on('change keyup click', function() {
 var price = $('.price').text().substr(1);
  var quantity =  $('.quantity').val();
  
  $('.total').text(price * quantity);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Total : <span class="total">$50.00</span></br>
Price : <span class="price">$50.00</span></br>
<input name="quantity" class="quantity" value="1" />
```

Comment: So your issue is that you're losing the `$` when you make a change?

Comment: Yes and also `.00` not showing on calculated price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the currency with a substring function:

```
var currency = $('.price').text().substr(0, 1);
```

...and then add it to the `text` function:

```
$('.total').text(currency + (price * quantity).toFixed(2)); // Adds $ and .00 decimals
```

Full code:

```
$('input[name=\'quantity\']').on('change keyup click', function() {
  var price = $('.price').text().substr(1);
  var currency = $('.price').text().substr(0, 1);
  var quantity = $('.quantity').val();

  $('.total').text(currency + (price * quantity).toFixed(2));

});
```

Comment: I don't want to add that manually. That is php generated and i have other currencies so  Any other way??

Comment: @protik changed my answer to automatically fetch the currency from the `.price` span. Would that work?